# Type a prop to accept either one interface or another interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-types

I have a function that can send requests to create and edit a todo with a single input prop.
I want to type the input to this function to accept only `CreateTodoInput` or `EditTodoInput`

```
export interface ICreateTodoInput {
  todoName: string;
  todoType: TodoType;
  todoContent:string;
  todoCompletionStatus: TodoCompletionStatus;
}
export interface IEditTodoInput {
  todoId: string;
  todoName?: string;
  todoType?: TodoType;
  todoContent?: string;
  todoCompletionStatus?: TodoCompletionStatus;
}
//(the `Todo...` types are just string enums)
```

Edit: I have tried `ICreateTodoInput | IEditTodoInput` but that is a union of the two types and will give errors `Property 'todoId' does not exist on type 'ICreateTodoInput'`

The docs mention conditional types which sounds like what I want, but not sure how I would add that to my react component

```
type EitherOr<T> = T extends ICreateTodoInput
  ? ICreateTodoInput
  : IEditTodoInput;//will this work?
```

the component in question

```
interface ITodoMutatorProps{
todoInput?: //<-- want to type this
}

export const TodoMutator = ({
  todoInput 
}: ITodoMutatorProps): JSX.Element => {
//if todoInput is type ICreateTodoInput 
    //send create request

//if todoInput is type IEditTodoInput 
    //send edit request
}
```

Comment: Just use the [Union literal](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_union.htm) syntax like `todoInput?: ICreateTodoInput | IEditTodoInput;`.

Comment: won't work since the interfaces differ in types

Comment: I would say that your union type is correct.  You need to make sure that the “if” part of your code is refining the types properly (aka, that it is a “type guard”).  You cannot access a property on the union unless it exists in both branches so you need to refine the type before you can use it for a create or edit request.

Comment: if (“todoId” in todoInput) should work as edit had an id but create doesn’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend a conditional type here.  What you are dealing with is a "[discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)".  You have a type which could be either an `ICreateTodoInput` or an `IEditTodoInput` and you need to know which one it is before you can use it for a create or edit action.

The simplest way to distinguish between the two type is by looking for the `todoId` property, which is present in `IEditTodoInput` but not in `ICreateTodoInput`.  TypeScript knows that if this property is present then your `todoInput` variable is an `IEditTodoInput`.

> Edit: I have tried ICreateTodoInput | IEditTodoInput but that is a union of the two types and will give errors Property 'todoId' does not exist on type 'ICreateTodoInput'

You cannot access a property on a union type unless it is declared in all branches of the union.  But you *can* [use the `in` operator to narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).

```
interface ITodoMutatorProps {
    todoInput: ICreateTodoInput | IEditTodoInput;
}

export const TodoMutator = ({
    todoInput
}: ITodoMutatorProps): JSX.Element => {
    if ("todoId" in todoInput) {
        editTodo(todoInput);
    }
    else {
        createTodo(todoInput);
    }
```

---

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mpDLxm)

Full code (with empty placeholders for your enums and functions):

```
enum TodoCompletionStatus { }

enum TodoType { }

function editTodo(input: IEditTodoInput) { }

function createTodo(input: ICreateTodoInput) { }

export interface ICreateTodoInput {
    todoName: string;
    todoType: TodoType;
    todoContent: string;
    todoCompletionStatus: TodoCompletionStatus;
}

export interface IEditTodoInput {
    todoId: string;
    todoName?: string;
    todoType?: TodoType;
    todoContent?: string;
    todoCompletionStatus?: TodoCompletionStatus;
}

interface ITodoMutatorProps {
    todoInput: ICreateTodoInput | IEditTodoInput;
}

export const TodoMutator = ({
    todoInput
}: ITodoMutatorProps): JSX.Element => {
    if ("todoId" in todoInput) {
        //todoInput is type IEditTodoInput 
        //send edit request
        editTodo(todoInput);
    }
    else {
        //todoInput is type ICreateTodoInput 
        //send create request
        createTodo(todoInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a nice website :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had no idea the term I wanted was `discriminated union`. Mentioning the type narrowing work that needed to happen in the component was useful too

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks :) I put it together to get a job and I did get a job so that's why I'm not on StackOverflow so much anymore.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I'm really happy for you that you have found a job. I believe this is a good one, since your knowledge is very deep.